# Visual Studio 2012 Installation fails on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit machine, but installation fails. I tried to install all versions (Premium, Ultimate etc..) but I'm getting the error below.

The machine is not domain joined and I'm logged in as administrative user. I was using Security Essentials but turned it off before the installation. Installation source is from MSDN.

[image]

The error log is too big to upload, but here is the important portion from the log:

> [1350:2188][2012-10-07T18:24:13]: MUX:  ERROR: The type initializer
>   for 'System.Windows.Media.FontFamily' threw an exception.
>   [1350:2188][2012-10-07T18:24:13]: MUX:  Stack:    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Typeface..ctor(FontFamily fontFamily, FontStyle
>   style, FontWeight weight, FontStretch stretch)    at
>   MS.Internal.Text.DynamicPropertyReader.GetTypeface(DependencyObject
>   element)    at
>   MS.Internal.Text.TextProperties.InitCommon(DependencyObject target)
>   at MS.Internal.Text.TextProperties..ctor(FrameworkElement target,
>   Boolean isTypographyDefaultValue)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.GetLineProperties()    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.EnsureTextBlockCache()    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
>   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean
>   forceInfinityV)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size
>   referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element,
>   Size constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Decorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
>   at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(Size constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
>   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
>   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisual()    at
>   System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double
>   requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight)    at
>   System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowImpl()    at
>   System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindow()    at
>   System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)    at
>   System.Windows.Window.Show()    at
>   Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.RunUI(ViewModelCommonUi
>   viewModel)    at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.InternalRun()
>   at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ManagedUx.Run()    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: How about showing those details?

Comment: Is there anything common among the installations, e.g. a security tool, any kind of domain membership or whatsoever? Are you using the latest MSDN installer source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it needed some components from VS 2010, so I installed VS 2010 first then install VS 2012 and it was successful.

After this I un-installed VS 2010.

It seems very weird, but this only worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly corrupted fonts. Try these 3 methods to fix the problem

[How to Repair Corrupted Fonts in Windows 7](http://techie-buzz.com/how-to/repair-corrupted-fonts-in-win7.html)

Comment: I tried the steps suggested in the article but still having the same problem.